# Maps location out by 12,742km - the other side of the world

Tags: gps, geolocation, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

OK, I am mystified.

We used to live in the UK. Two plus years ago we moved to New Zealand. My wife has just bought a brand new samsung galaxy note 10.1 (running 4.0). I have installed 4.2 on my eeePC.

When we run "Maps" BOTH devices show our location as our old house in the UK from
two plus years ago.

The galaxy note has a built in GPS. Location services are turned on. A GPS status and indeed other free apps show the correct location in New Zealand.

My eeePC does not have a GPS. We both created new gmail accounts for these devices.

Surely the built-in GPS should have priority over any guessed position nonsense.

My questions:

1) Where is it getting the old position from?
2) How can we fix the Galaxy Note 10.1? (my wife is not very happy)

Comment: Try clearing the cache for Google Maps

Comment: if you see a seperate app called Google Settings as seen [here](http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/nexusae0_2013-02-26-14.45.40_thumb.png) then please open it and check the settings for `Maps and latitude` and `Location` settings.

Comment: Are you using WiFi while checking location and you have the same WiFi router as before? Google uses WiFi access points to give coarse location fixes and these take time to update as it has to "learn" that the location of the WiFi access point has changed. More info can be found for example on [ZDNet](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/networking/how-google-and-everyone-else-gets-wi-fi-location-data/1664).

Comment: @onik's answer is the most likely here. To figure out, if you took your WiFi router with you: temporarily switch it off, and but a (borrowed) one in its place. See where Google puts you then.